# Актуален ли ещё Java EE?

Tags: java, java-ee

Ребят всем привет.Занимаюсь мобильной разработкой и теперь хочу начать изучать веб приложения .Начал с `Java EE`,но мне сказали забросить её так как она не актуальна и в качестве довыда дали статью на хабабр .
Реально-ли не стоит тратить время на `Java EE`,  ?Спасибо,если где-то в контексте ошибка ,не судите строго я не Русский и не хотел ни кого обидеть.И

Comment: актуальность интерпрайса никуда не делась - весь бизнес на нем сидит

Comment: Умеете воодушевть))))

Comment: Тыкайте пальцем в того, кто сказал про неактуальность, издевательски хохочите, обзывайте некомпетентным идиотом.Но самое главное - перестаньте прислушиваться к советам этого человека.

Comment: аха)Сергей в его опустили не на шутку ))))))но спасибо ответ вчеткой форме все ясно)

Comment: Интересная статистика по этому поводу и не только http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-2016/